# Setting up AD on Windows Server 2008 Server Core

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

I have setup a VM with Windows Server 2008 x64 R2 (Server Core). This obviously leaves out the GUI but only gives me a command prompt.

Using this, how can I setup AD?

http://www.petri.co.il/installing-remote-server-administration-tools-rsat-windows-vista.htm - This link provides details on an update for Vista to do configuration of the server from Vista (my host OS) but I am not on any of the supported versions.

Furthermore, if I type the following in the command prompt:

cclist

Which is supposed to list the services, the CMD says this is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Thanks

Comment: cclist is found in c:\windows\system32\ if I remember correctly.  I am not sure why core boxes do not honor path statements all the time but I have had the same issue from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

For what it is worth here is my notes I use when I setup a Core Server.

---

Core Setup Notes

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749081.aspx

core setup cheat sheat
http://blogs.technet.com/mempson/archive/2008/03/19/server-core-quick-reference-guide.aspx

```
Install the key and activate
cscript slmgr.vbs -upk  (uninstall the key)
WHATEVER YOU DO TOMMY DO NOT REBOOT HERE!
cscript slmgr.vbs -ipk XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX (install the key)
cscript slmgr.vbs -ato (activate)
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753802%28WS.10%29.aspx

To enable remote administration from Windows Vista/Windows 2008
Write the command in the Windows shell:

```
Cscript %windir%\system32\SCRegEdit.wsf /ar 0
```

and press the "Enter" button.

How to install Core as the first DC in a forest

http://blogs.technet.com/benp/archive/2008/06/20/how-to-configure-a-server-core-domain-controller-vanilla-to-first-dc-in-a-forest.aspx

Build an unattend file

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947034

```
FILENAME.txt

[DCINSTALL]
AutoConfigDNS=Yes
DomainNetBiosName=WTF
NewDomainDNSName=WTF.local
ReplicaOrNewDomain=DomainNewDomain=ForestForestLevel=3DomainLevel=3SafeModeAdminPassword=PUTPASSWORDHERE
RebootOnSuccess=Yes
```

---

No warranty on any code listed here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Vista Home then you are probably going to run into other problems because Home can't join a domain, but [RDP can be used](http://www.petri.co.il/managing-windows-2008-server-core-rdp.htm) from a Home computer.  This isn't a GUI but will allow remote connection to the cmd line.

I believe the cmd you are referring to is oclist, not cclist.

[MS documentation for Server 2008 Core](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753802%28WS.10%29.aspx) has instructions on configuring AD, DNS, DHCP, etc via the command line.  This can be done via local or RDP session.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a neat tool to help you get started: [Server Core Configurator](http://www.codeplex.com/CoreConfig)

Also, I have the original Core Configurator but as it was pulled from the web I don't think redistributing it would be advisable - but it rocks for setting up the basics including firewall rules and of course dcpromo without the need to prepare an unattend file manually.